# JFrame appears too small

Tags: java, swing

I'm building a basic Swing GUI, but in this small piece of code, I failed to have my components be there. The window doesn't seem to pack correctly so that it's way too small. What did I do wrong?

```
class TesterFont extends Font{
    TesterFont(){
        super(Font.MONOSPACED,Font.PLAIN,12);
    }
}

class TesterTextArea extends JScrollPane{
    final static int N_COLUMNS=24;

    TesterTextArea(int nRows){
        super(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(new JTextArea(nRows,N_COLUMNS){{
            setFont(new TesterFont());
            setLineWrap(true);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
        }});
    }
}

class TesterFrame extends JFrame{
    TesterFrame(){
        setTitle(Tester.class.getSimpleName());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        add(new TesterTextArea(10));
        add(new TesterTextArea(10));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Tester{
    void start(){
        new TesterFrame();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception{
        new Tester().start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing `add` to `super` in the constructor of `TesterTextArea`!